# Epiphany "Oops! Unable to display this website."

Tags: epiphany

When browsing with Epiphany, I get lots of *"Oops! Unable to display this website."*. 
Need to reload pages very often, say about 7 out of ten. I use Firefox now (downloaded from AppCenter), which is stable. But I like Epiphany for its speed. What could be a solution to failing to load pages? My system is updated daily and the internet connection is solid. In Firefox the same browsing actions never result in errors.

**Below the info in such an event:**

The site at “xxx” seems to be unavailable. The precise error was:

Error resolving 'xxx': Temporary failure in name resolution

It may be temporarily unavailable or moved to a new address. You may wish to verify that your internet connection is working correctly.

Comment: Check your packet loss `ping google.com `  wait 1 minute and press Ctrl+C. If you have packet loss that's likely the issue.

Comment: I've found this when clicking links in external software, and epiphany is opening them in the background, and then they only load when you go to Epiphany and refresh the page... Not sure if there is a focus issue too?

Comment: The ping is good, 11-12 ms. Doesn't miss a ping in a couple of minutes. I checked my DSL modem and no errors, nothing that could relate to it.

Comment: I switched to Firefox which performs reliable.

Answer (score 2):

The "Oops! Unable to display this website" message occurs when the WebKit process displaying the webpage crashes. (This happens in a secondary process to ensure the main Epiphany process does not crash.) Crashes are *always* a bug that should be reported to the developers so they can try to fix it. Such issues are usually also security vulnerabilities that could be exploited by a sufficiently-determined attacker, so reporting the crash can also help make Epiphany more safe to use.

Rarely, this might be a bug in Epiphany's code itself, but it's almost always a bug in WebKit, so it's best to report the issue on https://bugs.webkit.org. Prefix the bug title with [GTK] and be sure to select the WebKitGTK+ component to ensure that the right developers notice the bug. To be useful, the bug report needs to include a stack trace taken *with WebKit debug symbols*. This requires a bit of technical expertise, but it's not too hard. See https://wiki.gnome.org/Community/GettingInTouch/Bugzilla/GettingTraces for information on how to get a good stack trace.